# nokogiri and the href label

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri

I am not sure how to access the label part of the anchor href tag. The other question that looks at this doesnt really answer it for me.

I have this code:

```
 @name = page.css("#content").css("a")[1]
```

Which gives this result

```
<a href="/define.php?term=generation%20xerox&amp;defid=7167814">generation xerox</a>
```

I want to get at the "generation xerox" bit

I wouldnt mind getting at the href, I dont understand that either. I have read several other SO questions but I can't get it to work

Thanks in advance all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the label with `@name.text` and the link with `@name['href']`

See [doc](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html)